# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist, foreach

```
void topologicalSortUtil(int v, boolean visited[], Stack<Integer> stack, ArrayList<Integer>[] adj) {
        visited[v] = true;
        for (int i : adj[v]) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                topologicalSortUtil(i, visited, stack, adj);
            }
        }

        stack.push(v);
    }
```

Here, I am calling an array of arraylist. The error is in the enhanced for loop, as told by my IDE (IntelliJ). It seems like a perfectly valid call as adj[v] would return an ArrayList and the integer i catching each elements of the array as they come and then processing them in the recursive call.

@Alex Shesterov  and others, 
   Here is the code using which *adj* was generated.

```
    ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[n+1];
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
            arr[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        arr[1].add(Arrays.asList(8,6,2));
        arr[2].add(Arrays.asList(7));
        arr[3].add(Arrays.asList(6));
        arr[4].add(Arrays.asList(5,2));
        arr[5].add(Arrays.asList(4,2,3));
        arr[6].add(Arrays.asList(3,2,5));
        arr[7].add(Arrays.asList(2));
        arr[7].add(Arrays.asList(1,2,4));
```

Comment: adj is an array of `ArrayList<Integer>` type and in your foreach loop `int i` cannot hold an arraylist

Comment: Are you sure the error is in that code? It seems to be somewhere where you use the `Arrays` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in which you generate the array is incorrect and type-unsafe. You are probably getting warnings about "unsafe types" or "raw types" from the compiler. The following is a use of a raw type:

```
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[n+1];
```

You should never use the type `ArrayList` without some kind of type declaration.

You then initialize each of the elements of `arr` to be an `ArrayList<Integer>`. But since this is assigned to a raw typed array element, the compiler doesn't know that the element is an `ArrayList<Integer>` and doesn't warn you about your next step, which is the bad one:

```
arr[1].add(Arrays.asList(8,6,2));
```

You add an element to the list in `arr[1]`. The `add` method adds a *single* element, which is the object that is passed to it. And what is that object? It's a *`List`*, which is produced by `Arrays.asList(...)`.

So instead of having an `ArrayList<Integer>` you have a raw `ArrayList` which has a single element, and that element is a *list* of integer. And this, of course, cannot be cast to `Integer`.

Instead of using `add` you should have used `addAll`. The `addAll` method adds all the elements in the collection it receives to the collection on which it is called.

```
arr[1].addAll(Arrays.asList(8,6,2));
```

It would have been better not to mix arrays and lists, but to pass a list of lists and give it the appropriate type.

Try to avoid raw types and eliminate all raw type or unsafe type warnings from your code (not by `@SupressWarnings`!), unless you start programming libraries for generic collections and you know what you are doing.

Comment: Very detailed answer. I used addAll before you answered and it worked. But didn't really know 'why'. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Error is in method call.Probably when you are calling `topologicalSortUtil` first time. You are passing integer instead of list of integer

**Incorrect Method Call**

```
topologicalSortUtil(1,booleanArray,passingIntegerInsteadOfList,stack)
```

**ImplementedMethod**

```
void topologicalSortUtil(int v, boolean visited[], Stack<Integer> stack, 
    }
```

Comment: This is a bit cryptic. The method is recursive, it calls itself. Its parameters are `int`, `boolean []`, `Stack<Integer>` and `ArrayList<Integer>[]` and these are also the arguments in the call. So not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i understand `topologicalSortUtil `is recursive. But looks like error is in code which call `topologicalSortUtil` first time. For example `topologicalSortUtil ` first call may be from main method and then it will be recursive

Comment: I would re-write the answer if that is the case. It's not clear where you deduced that the user is actually calling the "Incorrect method call", and the "Implemented method" is not even syntactically correct. Just explain without adding code that doesn't exist.

Comment: `It's not clear where you deduced that the user is actually ..` to me it seems that is the only possibility based on code posted

Comment: Actually, look at Alex Shesterov's answer. It makes much more sense. Also, if the user tried to call the method with an integer instead of a list, he would get a **compile error**, not a runtime exception. And please read your two pieces of code carefully. Do you really believe they make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The exception suggests that the `adj` array, which is supposed to contain instances of `ArrayList<Integer>`, actually contains an `ArrayList` which has a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` as an element.

Thus, the enhanced loop runs into a `ClassCastException` when it hits such an element of the `ArrayList` and tries to "interpret" it as an `Integer`.

Please inspect and/or post the code which *builds* the `adj` array.

Also, please look for the *"Type safety"* and *"Raw types"* warnings in your code — you may have unsafely ignored a couple of them which led to this exception.

---

**Update:**

As expected, the problem is that you are adding *lists* as *elements* of the lists which are elements of the `adj`/`arr` array. 
E.g. the following lines:

```
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[n+1];
arr[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr[1].add(Arrays.asList(8,6,2));
```

would result in the following structure:

```
arr - array
  [0] : ...
  [1] : ArrayList (of lists) :
          [0] : List (of integers) : 
                  [0] : 8
                  [1] : 6
                  [2] : 2
  [2] : ...
  ...
```

[`List.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) adds a single element to the list.

What you need is the [`List.addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method, which adds *all elements from a collection* (and not the collection itself) into the list:

```
arr[1].addAll(Arrays.asList(8,6,2));
```

This would have produced the following structure:

```
arr - array
  [0] : ...
  [1] : ArrayList (of integers) :
          [0] : 8
          [1] : 6
          [2] : 2
  [2] : ...
  ...
```

---

Another note: [you should never use *raw generic types*](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224) — using explicit generic arguments would have produced a compile-time error for your code above, and the problem would have been very easy to find and fix.

Comment: please look into the code I pasted now. This part generates the adj.